# The same answer on two different questions. How to handle?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, duplicate-answers

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17044270/825757) asked which I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19434416/825757) several months ago. Today I had a comment on my answer which the poster linked to another answer. In looking at the other link I realized that the person posting the comment had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24225549/825757) that was a (in my opinion) a duplicate of the question I answered. Close vote made. What I then realized is the poster had asked a question, then posted an answer to the question and then posted the same answer on the original question I referenced above.

Other than voting to close the duplicate question, should I flag the answer since the two answers are identical? Should I do anything other than a close vote? In my eyes posting an answer to a question, then duplicating the question and answer isn't helpful to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is now closed.  As [Stephan Branczyk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260592/250725) suggested, the ***Meta Effect*** got the specific question closed.

For future, voting to close the question should always be the first step as it will give the community a chance to act on the question, but for times that they can't move quickly enough, and automatic moderator flag is raised when the same user posts the same exact answer on multiple questions.  A flag should have been raised automatically in this case, so when a moderator saw this flag, they would have closed the question as a duplicate and possibly deleted one of the answers.

But for times that you don't think a mod will get to the flag fast enough, or the answers are not exact copy-and-paste duplicates and hence won't trigger the automatic flag then you have some options.  Asking a question on meta will certainly help, but I'm of the position that we don't need a new meta post every time something **thinks** a question needs to get closed fast.  I think the best option outside the normal feature of the system is you can visit an appropriate SE chat room and enlist support there.  You'll find enough >3K users to get the question closed, and you might even find enough 20K users who can help delete the duplicate answers if it needs it be deleted.

Comment: @hakre considering I was the 5th close vote, I didn't read him wrong.  But I did make a typo :)

Comment: Okay, that was not obvious to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Calling attention to the question on Meta probably did the trick.

I predict that the question will be closed and/or downvoted into oblivion very quickly (assuming it doesn't get deleted before then).