# Two different questions by the same user with the same answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

First I just read this MSO [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250087/duplicate-flagged-posts-is-re-use-of-existing-answers-ok) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260591/the-same-answer-on-two-different-questions-how-to-handle) one too, but the situations are not all that similar to what I need to ask about.

The problem is that the same user asked two different questions (they seem to be different, but maybe it's a kind of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). This is the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753142/validation-problems-with-prime-faces) , and this is the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754318/validation-problems-when-i-have-2-forms-on-the-same-page-primefaces) one, then he took the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754728/4170582) of the first one that was provided by another user and used it as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28754991/4170582) to his second question. Which only means that it's all about the same problem and it's a duplicate question.

Could you please advise how scenarios like that should be handled? Do I need just to flag it as duplicate or the reason will not be clear? I thought also on using custom flag, but I don't think that it's something that is worth bothering the moderators with.

**NB:** I have no doubts on the user's general behavior, as most of his questions are correct and normal, so my interest is only about the way to handle that kind of situation.

### UPDATE:

For users who just saw my question, the OP's answer was deleted from the second question (by him or SO users as not good behavior to copy other's answers), so maybe you will see the two questions as not duplicate but for the OP that meant one single question and the first question's answer was sufficient and resolved his issue.

Comment: Also I feel it's really rude of him to repost another user's answer as a self answer and not even linking to the original post.

Comment: The original answerer also answered the second question...

Comment: @MatthieuM. thanks for replying, but I already checked the history of their answers both, and to be honest I don't doubt any fraudulent use, I think he is only trying to help and maybe he didn't paid attention that it's the same issue behind the scenes (as the questions in their form doesn't seem to be the same)

Comment: @AndréDaniel Yes you are right. Meanwhile, I just saw that Stephan Branczyk dded new comments to the second answer asking him to delete his entire question, seems to me the best way to handle that, what do you think ? (I'm not the downvoter :) )

Comment: Reposting answers of other users (especially without attribution) is clearly worth a moderator flag.

Comment: How are they duplicates?  The first question is about performing client-side validation instead of using AJAX, and the answer is to add a parameter to web.xml.  The second question is about duplicated error messages, and the answer is to set the gobalOnly attribute to true.  They are not the same at all.

Comment: @dennisdeems I do agree that the question seems to be different and thats why I'm asking here, but now the OP deleted his answer from the second question (Or maybe SO users did) so it doesn't appear like a dupe, for the OP the answer of the first question was sufficient for both (hope you understand me as my english is very bad)

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd downvote and flag as a duplicate of the first question.

Unless you see this behavior repeating several times I don't think a custom flag is necessary, and even then, downvoting and closing the questions will eventually lead him to a ban.

Answer (score 2):

Vote to close one of the questions as duplicate of the other. (Assuming the two questions are closely related enough to be considered as such.)

Then, if you care to do so, leave a comment to the answerer to the effect that this would have been a preferable course of action for her/him to take, rather than posting a duplicate answer.

Don't get mods involved unless this behaviour is a rampant problem on this particular user's part.

(Do you see what I did there?)